# How to insert data into a mongodb collection using the c# 2.0 driver?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

1. I'm using the `MongoClient` in my c# console application to connect to MongoDB

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc0

2. My code

   ```
     class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
           const string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

           // Create a MongoClient object by using the connection string
           var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

           //Use the MongoClient to access the server
           var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

           var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");

           var entity = new Entity { Name = "Tom" };
           collection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
           var id = entity._id;          
       }
   }

   public class Entity
   {
       public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. After successfully running the code above, I'm unable to find this record in the MongoDB database using this command:

   ```
   db.entities.find().pretty()
   ```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the method I created for inserting data into MongoDB, which is working fine now.

```
static async void DoSomethingAsync()
{
    const string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

    // Create a MongoClient object by using the connection string
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

    //Use the MongoClient to access the server
    var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

    //get mongodb collection
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");
    await collection.InsertOneAsync(new Entity { Name = "Jack" });
}
```

Comment: if you know why this code works, and why the other one failed, it would be helpful to include such info in your answer.  Knowing **why** something works or not (even if the reason is "bug in the API") can help the reader improve far beyond helping him in just this one narrow example.

Comment: In console application, I guess it was exiting the application before the store was created. I added the async method, followed by readline in main static method and it started working. static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           DoSomethingAsync();
           Console.ReadLine();
        }

Comment: lookd like async method and await keyword at the collection.InsertOneAsyc did the trick as mentioned by @Inba in the post above

Comment: async/await would wait and indeed if a timeout error the catch block would then get hit.    I'm not sure that is the reason it is "working" because of adding async/await

Answer (score 9):

for .net 4.5 and greater versions and mongodriver 2x series follow the below code

```
var Client = new MongoClient();
var MongoDB = Client.GetDatabase("shop");
var Collec = MongoDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("computers");
var documnt = new BsonDocument
{
    {"Brand","Dell"},
    {"Price","400"},
    {"Ram","8GB"},
    {"HardDisk","1TB"},
    {"Screen","16inch"}
};
Collec.InsertOneAsync(documnt);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: MongoDB is already a namespace, I assume this code won't compile?

Comment: You are correct it is a Namespace but, you have probably defined it in the using statements, so this code would work fine. There would be no issue using this as a local variable name. Although personally I would avoid this, more for my own confusion than anything else.

Answer (score 9):

The reason is you need to wait to get the store to create the document. In this case        collection.InsertOneAsync(entity); the execution exit before creating the document.

Either Console.ReadKey() or collection.InsertOneAsync(entiry).Wait() or any other form of stopping exit for a fraction of second will do the trick.