# How to insert data in MongoDB dll in C#

Tags: .net, mongodb

I am trying to insert data to my local MongoDB like below:

```
public void insert(FilePath file)
{
    try
    {
        IMongoCollection<FilePath> collection = _db.GetCollection<FilePath>("FilePath");
        BsonDocument bson = new BsonDocument{
            {"filePath",file.Path},
        };
        collection.InsertOne(bson);
    }
    catch { };
}
```

But visual studio compiler annoying me like "**invalid argument**"
I try to give other 2 parameters too, but the result same?

Comment: Did you add the file path?

Comment: no because it gave me that error

Comment: look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327856/how-to-insert-data-into-a-mongodb-collection-using-the-c-sharp-2-0-driver

Comment: ok sur this is solved my problem with a clue like that Task tresult = collection.InsertOneAsync(file);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you

```
Task tresult = collection.insert(file);
```

[check this answer for resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327856/how-to-insert-data-into-a-mongodb-collection-using-the-c-sharp-2-0-driver)