# How to save information from UI to mongoDB collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, razor

I'm currently looking for this, i have a modal that contains some textbox, user have to fill them and then i'd like to save the information inside a collection in mongo. A class ConnectionHandler.cs is used to connect to database and we are using mongoentities. So i have this :

```
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    using Project.My.Core.Entities.MongoEntities;

   namespace Project.My.Core
{
     public class ConnectionHandler<T> where T : IMongoEntity
     {
        public MongoCollection<T> MongoCollection { get; private set; }

        public ConnectionHandler()
         {
           var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";

           //// Acceder à la chaine de connection
           var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

           //// Acceder au serveur
           var mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();

          //// Acceder à la BD 
          const string databaseName = "MyDB";
          var db = mongoServer.GetDatabase(databaseName);
          //// Acceder aux collection la BD (tables en langage relationnel...)
          MongoCollection = db.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);

    }
}
```

}

My modal content is inside a partial view like this :

```
@using Project.My.Web.Administration.Models
@model GarantieViewModel

<div id ="userinput" class="form-panel-modify">
    <div class="form-horizontal style-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.NomUser, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.NomUser, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.PrenomUser, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.PrenomUser, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.EntrepriseUser, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.EntrepriseUser, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.EmailUser, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.EmailUser, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.TelephoneUser, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.TelephoneUser, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.whoareyou, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.whoareyou, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.mutuelle45, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.mutuelle45, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.NumeroOrias, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.NumeroOrias, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:50px;">
<input type="submit" disabled="true" class="btn btn-default" style="color:    #ffffff;background-color:#48bcb4;border-color: #48bcb4;">
</div>
```

And finally my modal is here :

```
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content" style="height:650px;width:600px;text-align:center">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Informations</h4>
                    <p><b>Pour lancer la comparaison vous devez d'abord renseigner vos informations</b></p>
                </div>
                @Html.Partial("_ModalContent")
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

So, after looking everywhere i can't do what i want. I just want the information of my modal content to go inside a collection named "UserInformation" for example.

If someone could help with this it would be great ! Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert data into a mongodb collection using the c# 2.0 driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327856/how-to-insert-data-into-a-mongodb-collection-using-the-c-sharp-2-0-driver)

Comment: I don't think so, because it's not the way i want to put my information inside the database .. I want to take the input user and put it not to create a document by myself

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but it seems as though you may be having a problem with submitting, or reading, the form data in your controller to pass to your data provider? Is that right?

Comment: I have a problem to understand how to manage this : passing my user input inside my database after the user validate